# React-Redux-Forms enable checkbox in another react component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-redux-form

I have given someone else's React project which is using the React-Redux-Form (this is not the redux-form) and there is a need to enable a checkbox which is on another React Component based upon a value being entered in a textbox in the React-Redux-Form. By defult the checkbox is disabled and should only be enabled if a value is present.

Searching on the Internet have failed to find an example in which to use. Can anyone help?

Comment: the short version is that you need to get the value of that textbox from within the component it exists, and set it to state in redux, that way the other component with  the button can read it's value and respond accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for replying. To be clear I access the textbox from within the component that has a checkbox. Are you able to share an example so I have this clear in my head

Comment: it would be better for you to go ahead and post the relevant code you already have, to be better able to give you a clear answer than for me to write up a bunch of code to give you one ;)

Comment: and to also outline what the problem really is, if you have access to the value of the textbox from inside the component that the checkbox is in - then this should be pretty straightforward...are you getting errors? Is it silently failing? or do you just not know how to approach enabling/disabling even though you have the info available in the correct place to write the logic?

Comment: I wish I could copy and paste the code for you, but it is on an air gap system. I don't have any errors as I am researching into the area as I am playing catch-up on a technology that I am learning on the fly.

Comment: The developer who I have inherited this from has used React-Redux-Forms with ReactSaga as his model. The checkbox is on a sidebar, all I am trying to work out is how to access from the form if it is the form that I need to access and then set the checkbox to enable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137670/discussion-between-andy5-and-holymoly).

Comment: i hopped in chat but didn't see you

Comment: To keep things simple could you give me an example of how to set a html element in one control from a value set in a form in another control and I will try and work it from there somehow

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very rough example, and is not intended to run - simply show the flow of how to do it:

The component with the input field might have something like:

```
  //1) this is setting a local state, when the user submits you can send it to redux so that it is available across the app.

  this._saveInputToLocal() {
    var emailRegEx = /^.+@.+\..+$/i;

    this.setState({
      email: e.target.value 
      }, function() {
    }.bind(this));
  },

 //2) when the user clicks submit - send the input to redux
 //lets assume this is saved into a property on state called `formInput`:

  this._saveInputToRedux() {
    const = { dispatch }
    dispatch(saveUserInput(this.state.email)) 
  },  


  render: function(){        
    return (
      <div className={`field email ${css(styles.emailContainer)}`}>
        <input
          type='email'
          placeholder={ 'helloworld@code.com' }
          onChange={this._saveEmailToState}
        />   
      </div>
      <button type='submit' onClick={this._saveInputToRedux}>Submit</button>
    )
  }
});
```

So you see, you have a few things: a function that updates a local state, and one that handles the submit - where the value of the local state fires and action that will store that value in redux. Don't forget to import `connect` so that you have `dispatch` available to you on props, and also don't forget to import your action into the component.

Now, In the *other* component that has the checkbox:

```
  // 3) assuming you have mapped your redux state to your props you make a function that checks for a valid input value:

  this._hasValidValue() {
    const { formInput } = this.props
    return formInput && formInput !== null && formInput !== undefined && formInput.length > 0 
  }

//here in the render you display either an enabled or disabled checkbox based on if you have a valid input from the other component. Because this is based on state, this component will re-render when state is updated (goes from invalid to valid or vice versa) 

  render: function(){ 
    return (
      <div className="checkbox">
      { hasValidValue() 
        ? <input type="checkbox" name="some-name" />
        : <input type="checkbox" name="some-name" disabled/>
      }
    )
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your example. Very helpful. Just one more question, can this onChange event still occur without the need for a submit button being clicked? If so, what do I need to change?